# How to automatically generate Google Apps Script code for a new spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically generate Google Apps Script code that belongs to a new spreadsheet?

I am automatically generating new spreadsheets on a weekly basis and I want to have a button on them that executes an Apps Script function (by button I mean drawing with a function attached).

I'm able to generate new spreadsheets with the appropriate drawings by duplicating another spreadsheet. I can get those drawings from the new spreadsheet using `sheet.getDrawings()`. I can also set the function that the drawing executes with `setOnAction()`. However, it doesn't recognize the function because the function isn't in the same AppsScript code as the drawing. Is there a way to automatically generate some Apps Script code for the new sheets? Or is there a workaround so the drawing knows where the external function is? Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Google workspace addons instead of a editor addon](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/overview) instead. These, when installed, will be available on all spreadsheets.